# how to override compareTo(). If it's possible

Tags: java

```
public int compareTo(Object obj){
   Books bk = (Books) bk;
   return this.id - obj.id;
}
```

my code works fine when `id` is an `Integer` and when is a positive value. Is it possible for `id` to be a negative value? How to change the code for that?

Comment: Are you using Java 1.4? `Comparable` is generified starting with Java 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work :D

`return (this.id > bk.id ) ? -1: (this.id < bk.id) ? 1:0 ;`

this works how I wanted it but thanks for your reply

Comment: Your original implementation was as valid as this.

Comment: @SJuan76 Not quite. If id can be very large, the subtraction can give different, probably incorrect results due to wrap-around. For example, Integer.MAX_VALUE-(-3) is negative. Doing the comparisons always works.

Answer (score 2):

The following is perhaps the easiest way to implement it:

```
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
   Books bk = (Books)obj;
   return Integer.compare(this.id, bk.id);
}
```

Your current version is almost correct, except that it is susceptible to integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you override `compareTo` you get to define the answer to these questions. It completely depends on your program whether it's possible for `id` to be a negative value. The question you have to ask yourself is "what does it mean for one book to be 'larger' (or smaller) than another one?". If the answer is just which ever has the larger id is a larger Book, then your implementation is fine, except for one minor mistake:

```
public int compareTo(Object obj){
   Books bk = (Books) obj;
   return this.id - bk.id;
}
```

Comment: I would use "goes before" or "goes after" better than "larger", but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** be able to return a negative value. From the `Comparable` specification, if

```
a.compareTo(b) > 0
```

then

```
b.compareTo(a) < 0
```

Otherwise you could not use `compareTo()` to stablish an **order**